# Cannot import name 'views',.Python, Django

Tags: python, django

I have read many answers in this forum, but they does not solve my problem. I will be very grateful for help.

My file views.py returns this error:

```
from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__' (C:/Users/tymot/Desktop/weather app/env/Environemnt/the_weather/weather/views.py)
```

**views.py (Environemnt\the_weather\weather)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html') #returns the index.html
```

**urls.py (Environemnt\the_weather\weather)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),  #the path for our index view
]
```

**urls.py (Environemnt\the_weather\the_weather)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('weather.urls')),
```

**templates(the_weather\weather\templates\weather)**
only file index.html

**Directory**

```
-the_weather
--the_weather
---__init__
---setting
---urls
---wsgi
--weather
---migrations
----__init__
---templates
----weather
-----index
---__init__
---admin
---apps
---models
---tests
---urls
---views
--db
--manage.py
```

I try use to resolved my problem `from __future__ import absolute_import`, or `homepage import views`. I else try copy views.py to directory templates (and modify its code)  but unfortunately it not work

Comment: You write `urlpatterns` in `views.py`?

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7 Django 1.X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate your `views` and `urls` create a new module (file)  `urls.py` in your app, in your case it is `weather` folder, and add these code there, and remove it from `views.py`, you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) about it to understand it better.

**Path** : `the_weather/weather/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),  #the path for our index view
]
```

**Path** : `the_weather/weather/views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html') #returns the index.html template
```

Comment: My  views now:
`from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html')`

My urls.py in weather now:
`from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),  #the path for our index view`

but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: i update my answer try it, i wrote the `filepath` where you need to put your code

Comment: But these `ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from '__main__'` i see now in my urls.py file.

Comment: can you edit your answer, and put there all `traceback` ?

Comment: try to use `from weather import views`

Comment: it's done, i add most important file in actual version.

Comment: "try to use from weather import views" - No module named 'weather'. Maybe it's important. I have my directory (the_weather) in virtual environment.

Comment: how do you run your project and from where ?

Comment: I run my project from the directory weather. The same directory in which it is located manage.py. 
I use to it GIT Bash from the command 'python manage.py runserver'

Comment: can you send me  your code or give me the link from git repository if you have, i want to look because i don't understand why it raise the error

Answer (score 1):

You would need to put your views.py file in your weather folder. Make sure it is in the right weather folder, I am guessing you have two weather folders. Also make sure these codes are right;

#Path : the_weather/weather/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),  #the path for our index view
]
```

#Path : the_weather/weather/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'weather/index.html') #returns the index.html template
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this

```
from .views import index
```

Comment: i try use it in my url.py . Answer from PyCharm is `No module named '__main__.views'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: Could you please share the screenshots of your code and error traceback... both important..

Answer (score 0):

There may be separate folder of urls and views.py
what you have to do is you have to write
from appname import views
suppose your app name is myapp
you have have to write
from myapp import views

Answer (score 0):

use should create new url.py in weather and write code in views.py

url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

write code in urls.py of your project

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   path('wheather/',include('wheather'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had Similar problem,  it didn't solved, till I added an empty views.py in root in example, in your case add to Environemnt\the_weather\the_weather

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

[image: click for image]

[image: click for image]

In `formsdemo\formsdemo\__init__.py`, I changed the import code to `from forms app import views`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
import main.views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', main.views.home_page, name="home_page"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was also facing the same issue. I was continuously getting server errors but then I figured out it was a simple error.

**go to the urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = index),  #the path for our index view
]
```

I just had to remove  `name = index` and the server worked with 0 errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMkiy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from formsApp(folder containing view file) import views

from views import *
```